# How to use 2D Arrays in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

How to allocate a 2D array of size MXN? And how to traverse that array in CUDA?

```
__global__ void test(int A[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE], int B[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE],int C[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE])
{

    int i = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int j = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    
    if (i < BLOCK_SIZE && j < BLOCK_SIZE)
        C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];

}

int main()
{

    int d_A[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
    int d_B[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
    int d_C[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];

    int C[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];

    for(int i=0;i<BLOCK_SIZE;i++)
      for(int j=0;j<BLOCK_SIZE;j++)
      {
        d_A[i][j]=i+j;
        d_B[i][j]=i+j;
      }
    

    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE); 
    dim3 dimGrid(GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE); 

    test<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_A,d_B,d_C); 

    cudaMemcpy(C,d_C,BLOCK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int i=0;i<BLOCK_SIZE;i++)
      for(int j=0;j<BLOCK_SIZE;j++)
      {
        printf("%d\n",C[i][j]);
    
      }
}
```

Comment: You cant take back the value of 2D array with cudaMemcpy, instead you have to use cudaMallocPitch or cudaPitchPtr with cudaMalloc3D as @Dave said

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How to allocate 2D array:

```
int main() {
    #define BLOCK_SIZE 16
    #define GRID_SIZE 1
    int d_A[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
    int d_B[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];

    /* d_A initialization */

    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE); // so your threads are BLOCK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE, 256 in this case
    dim3 dimGrid(GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE); // 1*1 blocks in a grid
    
    YourKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_A,d_B); //Kernel invocation
}
```

How to traverse that array:

```
__global__ void YourKernel(int d_A[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE], int d_B[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE]){
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (row >= h || col >= w) return;
    /* whatever you wanna do with d_A[][] and d_B[][] */
}
```

I hope this is helpful, and also you can refer to [CUDA Programming Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory) about Matrix Multiplication

Comment: @user621508 while this will work, it just creates one huge linear array in device memory. You also can use [cudaMalloc3D](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g04a7553c90322aef32f8544d5c356a10.html#g04a7553c90322aef32f8544d5c356a10) to allocate two-dimensional arrays that are optimized for 2D-data access. I didn't know whether you just wanted the indexing of a 2D-array or the performance.

Comment: @username_4567, that's what /* d_A initialization */ stands for. However memory freeing is absent.

Comment: the actual content of /* d_A initialization */ is also an important part of the answer. Can you provide it as well?

Comment: Cuda kernels do not use return

Answer (score 12):

The best way would be storing a two-dimensional array A in its vector form.
For example you have a matrix A size nxm, and it's (i,j) element in pointer to pointer representation will be

```
A[i][j] (with i=0..n-1 and j=0..m-1).
```

In a vector form you can write

```
A[i*n+j] (with i=0..n-1 and j=0..m-1).
```

Using one-dimensional array in this case will simplify the copy process, which would be simple:

```
double *A,*dev_A; //A-hous pointer, dev_A - device pointer;
A=(double*)malloc(n*m*sizeof(double));
cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_A,n*m*sizeof(double));
cudaMemcpy(&dev_A,&A,n*m*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); //In case if A is double
```