# How do you create a 2d array in cuda

Tags: c, cuda

For practice, I'm working on making a simple matrix initialization program in cuda.  I made a little sequential version for reference as a starting point.  It just creates an n by m array and fills it with doubles.  I've been reading through other posts and documentation, but I'm pretty confused and I was hoping someone could explain to me how to initialize a 2d array in cuda in a similar manner of n by m size as I did below.  I would also appreciate insight on how to fill that cuda matrix if anyone would be willing to explain.

Hi again, in regards to it being a possible duplicate, I should elaborate. The linked post doesn't really explain anything, it's just sample code and it's one of the posts that I previously viewed but don't understand because it isn't explained.  Thank you.

Sequential version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>

int n,m, i, j;
double count;

void update(int n, int m, double arr[][m]){
  for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(j=0; j<m; j++){
      count++;
      arr[i][j] = count;
    }
  }
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  assert(argc==3);
  n = atoi(argv[2]);
  m = atoi(argv[1]);

  double (*arr)[n][m] = malloc(sizeof *arr);
  update(n,m,arr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use 2D Arrays in CUDA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029920/how-to-use-2d-arrays-in-cuda)

Comment: `double (*arr)[m] = malloc(n * sizeof *arr);` – I don't think that does what you think it does. And why all variables global??

Comment: Detail; In C, `arr` in `double (*arr)[m]` is not a 2D array, but a [pointer to an array m of doubles](https://cdecl.org/?q=double+%28*arr%29%5B42%5D+).  `double arr[n][m]` is a 2D array.

Comment: @chux pssst ... pointer to array of m doubles.

Comment: To create a pointer to a 2D array, C code could use `double (*arr)[n][m] = malloc(sizeof *arr);`

Comment: I can change the variables to be local if you'd prefer, that would make more sense.

Comment: @chux thank you, I'll update accordingly then

Comment: Cuda is not my strength.  Good luck

Comment: @Swordfish On 2nd thought, perhaps OP does want `double (*arr)[m] = malloc(n * sizeof *arr);` even if it is not a proper 2D array.  Hmmm its late.

Comment: okay @chux thanks again for your previous help

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643682/cuda-using-2d-and-3d-arrays/45644824#45644824) may be of interest

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate 2D array in 1D, keeping data row by row. So that 2D array:
[a,b][c,d] becomes [a,b,c,d]. To make things simple you can write a wrapper class providing such functionality.

Here is the demo (not 100% disasterproof, but working) of this idea

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

typedef int TYPE;

// NOTE: copy consturctor and = operator need to be overloaded as well
template<class T>
struct Matrix
{
    Matrix(int r, int c) : rows(r), cols(c) {
        data = new T[r*c];
    }
    ~Matrix() {
        // As we allocated memory it needs to be freed upon destruction
        delete[] data;
        data = nullptr;
    }
    int rows, cols;
    T* data;
    T* operator[](int row) {
        // Returns pointer to "ROW", further call to [] on result will retrieve item at column in this row
        return data + (row*cols);
    }
};

// Simple cuda kernel 
__global__ void add(TYPE *a, TYPE *b, TYPE *c, int rows, int cols) {
    // Get element row and col
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    // If kernel block/grid is not sized perfectly make sure not to step outside data bounds
    if(row < rows && col < cols)
    {
        int idx = row*cols + col;
        c[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx];
    }
}

int main() {
    // m3 = m1 + m2 using cuda
    int rows = 5, cols = 5, total = rows * cols;
    Matrix<TYPE> m1{ rows,cols }, m2{ rows,cols }, m3{ rows,cols };

    // Initialization as 1D array
    for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)  {
        m1.data[i] = i;
    }

    // Or initialization as 2D array
    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            m2[r][c] = r*cols + c + 100;

    for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)  std::cout << m1.data[i] << ", ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) 
            std::cout << m2[r][c] << ", ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    // CUDA part
    TYPE *d_m1, *d_m2, *d_m3;

    // Allocation
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_m1, total * sizeof(TYPE));
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_m2, total * sizeof(TYPE));
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_m3, total * sizeof(TYPE));

    // Copy m1 and m2 to GPU
    cudaMemcpy(d_m1, m1.data, total * sizeof(TYPE), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_m2, m2.data, total * sizeof(TYPE), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Oversized on purpose to show row/col guard on add kernel
    dim3 grid(5, 5);
    dim3 block(5, 5);
    add <<< grid, block >>> (d_m1, d_m2, d_m3, rows, cols);

    // Copy result to m3
    cudaMemcpy(m3.data, d_m3, total * sizeof(TYPE), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(d_m1);
    cudaFree(d_m2);
    cudaFree(d_m3);

    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            std::cout << m3[r][c] << ", ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic of going to the trouble of writing a wrapper class and not using it on both the host and device. Further the OP is complaining that the many other answers to this question already on [SO] are apparently too hard to understand because of limited explanation. Your answer suffers from the same problem